# GLSL 3.2 mapping shader arguments

Tags: objective-c, opengl, shader

I'm trying to create a high-level Objective-C OpenGL shader wrapper that allows me to execute various GL shaders without a lot of GL code that clutters the application logic.

So something like this for a shader with two 'in' arguments to create a quad with a different color in every corner:

```
OpenGLShader* theShader = [OpenGLShaderManager shaderWithName:@"MyShader"];
glUseProgram(theShader.program);

float colorsForQuad[4] = {{1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 1.0 ....}}
theShader.arguments[@"inColor"] setValue:colorsForQuad forNumberOfVertices:4];

float positionsForQuad[4] = {{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}, {-1.0f, 1.0f, ....}}
theShader.arguments[@"inPosition"] setValue:positionsForQuad forNumberOfVertices:4];

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

The `setValue:forNumberOfVertices:` function looks like this:

```
int bytesForGLType = numBytesForGLType(self.openGLValueType);
glBindVertexArray(self.vertexArrayObject);
GetError();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vertexBufferObject);
GetError();

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesForGLType * numVertices, value, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GetError();

glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)self.boundLocation);
GetError();

glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)self.boundLocation, numVertices,
                              GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

I think the problem is that each argument has its own VAO and VBO but the shader needs the data of all arguments when it is executed.
I can obviously only bind one buffer at a time.
The examples I've seen so far only use one VAO and one VBO and create a C structure containing all the data needed.
This however would make my current modular approach much harder.

Isn't there any option to have OpenGL copy the data so it doesn't need to be available and bound when glDraw... is called?

**Edit**

I found out that using a shared Vertex Array Object is enough to solve the issue. 
However, I would appreciate some more insight on when things are actually copied to the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

The [glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) function takes these parameters:

void glVertexAttribPointer(
    GLuint index,
    GLint size,
    GLenum type,
    GLboolean normalized,
    GLsizei stride,
    const GLvoid * pointer);

I think the problem is that you insert the number of vertices into the "size" parameter. That is not what it is meant for. It controls how many components will the attribute have. When the vertex attribute is meant to be vec**3** "size" should be set to **3**, when using floats it should be 1 and so on.

EDIT: As Reto Koradi pointed out, using 0 as "stride" is fine in this case.

Comment: Setting the stride to 0 means that the attribute values are tightly packed. So that part is fine.

Comment: Ok, you might be right with that. I thought this determines how many elements there are in the buffer. How do I tell GL how many elements there are? Is that determined by the glBufferData parameter that reads "bytesForGLType * numVertices" in this case?

Comment: The number of elements to draw is determined in the drawing function itself (glDrawArrays), you correctly set it to 4. Also I just realized I didn't answer your original question at all, sorry. By the way, do you bind a different VAO every time you call setValue:forNumberOfVertices: or the same one? If they are different, the problem is that you can only have one active VAO at a time, so the shader only takes the input from the last bound VAO. Otherwise you can use multiple VBOs in a single VAO without any problems. Try using only one global VAO.